# ERROR: Your system is not ready to run Symfony projects

Tags: php, symfony

I've downloaded a Symfony application and then checked it using `php -f ./app/check.php`. However, I get:

```
 [ERROR]                                          
 Your system is not ready to run Symfony projects 


Fix the following mandatory requirements
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * Vendor libraries must be installed
   > Vendor libraries are missing. Install composer following
   > instructions from http://getcomposer.org/. Then run "php
   > composer.phar install" to install them.
```

However, there is no `composer.phar` file in this application. e.g.

```
php composer.phar install
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

Note: I already have composer installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Install composer following instructions from http://getcomposer.org/.`

Comment: Having composer installed doesn't mean you did it right... Where did you install composer? Run this command to find out `find / -iname "composer"`. Like the error message told you, I would suggest finding/removing the current coposer, and doing a proper install.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *right there* in the error message you received.

> Install composer following instructions from http://getcomposer.org/

Comment: @SnowCrash Then try just `composer` instead of `composer.phar`. You've either installed it globally or you didn't put the `.phar` for the local install method in the right place.

Comment: To follow the man literally - just download composer.phar from `getcomposer.org` and put to the folder where you want to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `composer.phar` run:

```
php composer install
```

I think that's what you need. If you install Composer, then you probably renamed it to `composer`, and that's the bin you run.